# In Java, is there a quick way to dump all arguments to a method?

Tags: java, logging

I often find myself wanting to just print (using the implicit toString() of each object) every argument to a method in Java. Is there a quick way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What, do you think this is ruby?

Comment: @Matt nothing wrong with logging detailed information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java programming language doesn't have a construct to do this.  However, you can do it with one of the AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) packages, such as [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).
In particular this thread might be a good starting point on how to achieve this:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg09939.html

My personal opinion, however, is that most of the time AOP is a scary overkill.

UPDATE: Oh, [here's](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/logging-with-spring-aop/) an easier way using Spring AOP, assuming you can use Spring.
Generally, Spring is much easier to use than pure AspectJ.

Comment: Scary overkill? Could you explain that a bit?

Comment: Well, you are basically modifying the behavior of your program via a mechanism completely external to the language and your source code.  I'm wary of things like that.  They make debugging and reading the source code (especially w/o AOP-aware IDE) a much more challenging process.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic way built into the language itself. However, there are some things that might suite your needs:

1. Your IDE may have macros to generate a `println`
2. If you are only interested in dumping arguments across some layer, and all invocations are through interface methods, you can use Java Proxies.
3. You can use some bytecode manipulation, either post compile or during classloading
4. Let someone do the hardwork of #3, and learn yourself AOP